# Quais as diferenças entre background e foreground threads?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, multithreading

Quais as diferenças entre estes dois tipos de *threads*: *background* e *foreground*?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

A única diferença é que as *background threads* não determinam a vida do ambiente de execução, elas não seguram uma aplicação rodando e dependem das *foreground threads* para continuar existindo. Se todas as *foreground threads* encerrarem, o *runtime* encerra independente se ainda existe *background threads* rodando, evidentemente encerrando estas também. E isto tem algumas implicações na maneira com isto é comunicado para a aplicação.

Em geral *threads* costumam rodar em *foreground*. Esse é o *default*. Apenas quando você roda uma *thread* que existe em função das outras em *foreground* é que esta deve ser configurada como *background*. *Threads* monitoras são um bom exemplo.

*Threads* gerenciadas pelo [ThreadPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) são *background* por *default*.

[Exemplo](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/0f13e370-df87-4eb3-9e44-e169e361b7a0/?Foreground%20and%20Background%20thread%20in%20C) demonstrando o funcionamento.

Pense em usar uma [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0) no lugar.

Fonte: [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quer dizer que uma thread _background_ é a mesma coisa que uma thread _daemon_?

Comment: Se está comparando com Java, de certa forma, não é a mesma coisa, mas é próximo.

Answer (score 5):

Threads em segundo plano são idênticos aos Threads de primeiro plano com uma exceção: um Thread de segundo plano não mantém o ambiente de execução gerenciado executando.
Ou seja: a diferença é que um¹ não impede que o aplicativo seja terminado, o outro², sim.

¹ Background Thread.

² Foreground Thread.

*O correto, independente do tipo de thread, é você ter cuidado com seus threads, para evitar que eles saiam de controle e o aplicativo tenha resultados inesperados.*

Fonte:

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads with one
>   exception: a background thread does not keep the managed execution
>   environment running.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Então, se eu tiver uma thread inicializada e meu programa encerrar, ela sera executada até o fim do seu processo?

Comment: Caso ela seja do tipo Foreground, o programa ficará rodando ela até o fim da Thread. Caso ela seja Background ela será interrompida e o programa é encerrado imediatamente.

Comment: @Tony se a thread background estiver em um trecho marcado como crítico, o sistema espera mais um pouco ou é *kill* mesmo?

Comment: [Não conheço como marcar um trecho como crítico, nem sei com certeza ele impediria o thread de finalizar, mas] Pela análise da documentação, que informa que o background thread será encerrado ao finalizar a aplicação, não se deve esperar que um trecho, mesmo que marcado como crítico seja executado neste hipotético background thread que estará sendo abruptamente encerrado.